# How to switch off messages on all kernels?

Tags: warning-messages, message-coding

I am using `ParallelMap` for my code,however, it gives some messages that don't affect the evaluation process but fill up the memory and take some more time. So, I want to turn off all messages on all kernels. I used `Quiet` but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to switch off messages on all kernels?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One way is to include Quiet in the function that you are mapping.

Comment: Does `Off[your message]` help?

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you, I don't get any more.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I tried it but it works only for the first kernel.

Comment: @cesm To use Sjoerd's solution, you need to evaluate the `Off[...]` in each kernel separately, i.e. do `ParallelEvaluate[Off[...]]`.  Don't forget to turn it back on if it might be useful!  (I'd feel safer with using `Quiet`)

Comment: @Szabolcs Would this come with a performance decrease if the function is being mapped many, many times?

Comment: @JustSomeOldMan Not sure. Using `Quiet` definitely improves performance, but I don't recall by how much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do it exactly as you would do it on the main kernel. Following example which throws a message when it divides by zero:

```
ParallelMap[1/# &, Mod[Range[30], 3]]
```

Some people prefer to switch specific messages off beforehand. This can be done with

```
ParallelEvaluate[Off[Power::infy]]
ParallelMap[1/# &, Mod[Range[30], 3]]
```

Or you use `Quiet` as suggested by Szabolcs directly in the function

```
ParallelEvaluate[On[Power::infy]]
ParallelMap[Quiet[1/#] &, Mod[Range[30], 3]]
```